# Facing issues while making scrapy crawl docs from a deep web

Tags: python, scrapy

I want my spider to crawl the number of "Follower" and "Following" info of each person. At this moment it gives 6 results only out of several thousands. How can I get the full results?

"items.py" includes:

```
import scrapy
class HouzzItem(scrapy.Item):
    Following = scrapy.Field()
    Follower= scrapy.Field()
```

Spider named "houzzsp.py" includes:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class HouzzspSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "houzzsp"
    allowed_domains = ['www.houzz.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.houzz.com/professionals']

    rules = [
            Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//li[@class="sidebar-item"]')),
            Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//a[@class="navigation-button next"]')),
            Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//div[@class="name-info"]'),
            callback='parse_items')
    ]    


    def parse_items(self, response):
        page = response.xpath('//div[@class="follow-section profile-l-sidebar "]')
        for titles in page:
            Score = titles.xpath('.//a[@class="following follow-box"]/span[@class="follow-count"]/text()').extract()
            Score1 = titles.xpath('.//a[@class="followers follow-box"]/span[@class="follow-count"]/text()').extract()
            yield {'Following':Score,'Follower':Score1}
```

Edit: Have made changes in the Rules and it is working as I expected.

Answer (score 1):

when using scrapy's `LinkExtractor` with the `restrict_xpaths` argument, you don't need to specify the exact xpath for the urls to follow. From [scrapy's documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html#module-scrapy.linkextractors.lxmlhtml):

> **restrict_xpaths (str or list)** – is an XPath (or list of XPath’s) which
>   defines regions inside the response where links should be extracted
>   from.

So the idea is to specify sections, so `LinkExtractor` will only look deep into those tags to find links to follow.

To summarize, don't add `a` tags inside `restrict_xpaths` (`@href` will be even worse), because `LinkExtractor` will find `a` tags inside the xpath you specified.

Comment: Thanks eLRuLL for your response. Removing "href" from Rule It gives 6 results out of several thousands results. What can I do at this moment to get the full results.

Comment: don't setup `a` tags, but something above them.

Comment: Thanks eLRuLL, for your reply. It seems that changing the Rule slightly from what I set earlier is working now. However, its hard to get the real pics what is happening in the command prompt cause it is running very swiftly. The website gets millions of records. By the way, is it possible to get data in csv up to what it has scraped already, if i shut down cmd forcefully.

Comment: I haven't used scrapy on windows to be honest, so maybe something could be different there, but from what I know, scrapy outputs the items as soon as it gets them, so any export functionality show have the items regardless of the spider not finishing correctly.

Comment: Thanks  eLRuLL, for your response. You are absolutely right. I did get results in csv even if I cancelled it on the half way.

Comment: Np, please remember to accept the answer if it helped you!

Comment: Your suggestion helped me find out a way to get to the destination. But that was not qualified enough to claim the answer moreover, you discouraged me to use "a" tag between Rule. Perhaps you are right but I got the result using that in my second rule. No offense meant. thanks a lot again.